# Asp.net MVC4 Dropwdownlist Retain Selected Value after Get

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a drop down list that is included in the _layout view of my application.
What i am trying to do is populate the list with Data from a sql server and then based on the value selected redirect the user to another view.

All is working fine except that when the user click Enter/Search the value of dropdownlist gets defaulted to the first value. As i am currently transitioning from Web Forms it's quite difficult and frustrating.

Here is the code for my Model

```
                 public class DomainNameViewModel
{
    private static readonly string ConStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["App"].ConnectionString.ToString();


    public string SelectedDomainId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> domains
    {
        get
        {

            List<SelectListItem> l = new List<SelectListItem>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spDomainList", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    l.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = sdr[0].ToString(), Value = sdr[1].ToString() });
                }

                return l;
            }

        }
```

The Code for controller.

```
     [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return PartialView(new DomainNameViewModel());
    }
```

The DomainName View

```
            @model app.Models.DomainNameViewModel

          @{
  Layout = null;
   }

          @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDomainId, Model.domains, new { @id   = "e1",@class = "bannerlist" })
```

And the code for _Layout view

```
                   @using (Html.BeginForm("Search","DomainSearch",FormMethod.Get))
    {
    @Html.TextBox("txtDomain", null, new { @class = "bannertextbox" , placeholder="Search for a Perfect Domain!" })
 @Html.Action("index","DomainName")
    <input type="submit" class="bannerbutton" value="Search" />
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: Added the DomainSearchController code.**

```
    public class DomainSearchController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /DomainSearch/

    public ActionResult Search(string txtDomain,string SelectedDomainId)
    {
        DomainNameViewModel Domain = new DomainNameViewModel();
        Domain.SelectedDomainId = SelectedDomainId;
       string check = Domain.ParseDomain(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtDomain), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(SelectedDomainId));

        string s = Domain.CheckDomains(check);
        ViewBag.Domain = Domain.DomainCheckResult(s);
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: ModelState should take care of that, my suspect would be DomainSearch is not properly setting the values for the model (modelbinding is not working as it should or you are performing some kind of redirect losing the modelstate)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quite shown/explained how exactly are you performing the redirect. But you will need to either pass the selected value in the query string to the target page or store in in a cookie or somewhere on the server like in the ASP.NET Session (beurk).

The reason you need to do this is because in ASP.NET MVC, contrary to classic WebForms there's no ViewState and you cannot retrieve the selected value on subsequent PostBack (there's neither such notion as PostBack in ASP.NET MVC).

Then in your child controller action you will need to retrieve the selected value from the query string or from the cookie or from the ASP.NET session (beurk) and set the `SelectedDomainId` property on your view model to this value.

For example:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new DomainNameViewModel();
    // here you need to set the SelectedDomainId property on your view model
    // to which the dropdown is bound to the selected value
    model.SelectedDomainId = Request["domain_id"];
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Assuming you decide to pass this value as query string parameter when redirecting you will need to keep this parameter on subsequent redirects in order to keep the state.

Comment: I've added the code for DomainSearchController. Am i doing something very stupidly wrong?